# Android studio download error while installing Emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

I've installed the android studio with sdk, while downloading the virtual device I'm getting this error. after this, it again tries to download the file Anyone faced this error or can help with this really appreciated.

> Packages to install:
>
> - Google Play Intel x86 Atom System Image (system-images;android-28;google_apis_playstore;x86)
>
> Preparing "Install Google Play Intel x86 Atom System Image (revision:
> 9)". Downloading
> http://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis_playstore/x86-28_r09.zip
>
> This download could not be finalized from the interim state. Retrying
> without caching.

Installed Android Studio:

```
Android Studio 3.6.1
Build #AI-192.7142.36.36.6241897, built on February 26, 2020
Runtime version: 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 1246M
Cores: 4
Registry: ide.new.welcome.screen.force=true
Non-Bundled Plugins: com.herbert.george.flutter-snippets, Dart, io.flutter
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your CPU architechture is mactched with your SDK image. For example, if your CPU is x86-architechture(e.g. AMD CPU), you should not download "x86_64" image.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32593568)